# Connecting Nexus S to Eclipse under Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, nexus-s

Trying to get my Nexus S recognized under Ubuntu Linux but DDMS is just showing ?????????? for the device. If I do 'adb devices' it says no permissions.  I've updated my /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules to include the output from lsusb but to no avaial. Anyone know how to get this thing recognized?

This is my udev config:

```
# Bus 002 Device 003: ID 22b8:41db Motorola PCS Motorola Droid (USB Debug)
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE=="0666"

# Bus 002 Device 003: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc.   << nexus s
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE=="0666"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind - had to restart the udev service. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptoms and realized from the post above that it did not have a GROUP="plugdev" at the end contrarily to what is suggested in the android [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html). Removing the GROUP entry made it work for Ubuntu 10.04 with Nexus S

Comment: Nice catch. Not sure why your user wouldn't already be in the plugdev group as it's a default group for Ubuntu users. Could be your username & groups were migrated up from older version of Ubuntu, before plugdev was a default group.

Comment: are you using ubuntu as host OS or as guest OS, such as vbox guest on a win7 host?  I have same problem in this post: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=42605&p=229277#p229277

Comment: @wufoo: I think you hit it right on. I did migrate from an earlier version of ubuntu.

Comment: @GeorgeW: I am using ubuntu 10.04 as my host os, no virtual machine in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and was confounded until I realized that I hadn't yet turned on USB debugging on the phone.